# Creating a highly customized Work Item in Azure DevOPs through the API using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

I would like to programmatically create Work Items using the Azure DevOps API from a web application. There are many resources on this like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/create-bug-quickstart?view=azure-devops), so I have an idea on how to achieve it. What I'm uncertain about is how to assign values to highly customized fields using the .Net client. We've added a lot of custom drop downs and fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customized field is defined in the path `/fields/Custom.CustomFieldName`.

For example, i have a custom field named `Fix Version`. I can assign value to it by referring to the path in below patchDocument:

```
new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
         Operation = Operation.Add,
         Path = "/fields/Custom.FixVersion",
         Value = "1.2.0.0"
     }
```

You can get all the WIT Fields in your project using Method `WorkItemTrackingHttpClientBase.GetFieldsAsync`. See client library [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi.workitemtrackinghttpclientbase.getfieldsasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet).

You can aslo check out [Fields - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) restful api.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. What would the case be for a custom work item? We aren't using any of the standards ones like Tasks, Bugs, etc. We have our own which we've called "Issue"

Comment: It works for the custom work item too. When you update a custom field for a custom work item, the path is still `/fields/Custom.CustomFieldName`.  You can get the fields of a specific work item by using [work item type fields api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types%20field/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)